# Django admin page Removing 'Group'

Tags: django

How do I delete the model groups admin page? I want to show that by default, the group model. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use the `unregister` method :

Add to the admin.py file :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Comment: I'm getting "django.contrib.admin.sites.NotRegistered: The model Group is not registered"

Comment: So, I was getting that error because `'django.contrib.auth'` was below my app in `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple in `settings.py`, I changed the order, now it works :D

Answer (score 7):

You need to **check the order** of `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. Basically, your app should be listed *after* the `django.contrib.auth`.

Use the following code to `unregister` the Group inside `admin.py` file of your app:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Comment: Could you further elaborate why the ordering of INSTALLED_APPS caused this problem to take place?