# Import-export module works not with User model for me in Django

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am trying to import new users to original User model form the Django admin site. I used to add the users one-by-one manually to the model but now I need to import lots of users and I need a solution to bulk import. I tried the code below, but I have an error:

```
django.contrib.admin.sites.NotRegistered: The model User is not registered
```

Please help me to solve this.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources

class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id','username','first_name', 'last_name', 'email' 'password1', 'password2')

class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','username','first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    resource_class = UserResource
    pass

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Your User is an AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser? If is, you need to point him on `settings.py` typing `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'YourApp.YourModelName'`

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584102/django-contrib-admin-sites-notregistered-the-model-user-is-not-registered-i-g) help?

Comment: Mine is AbstractUser.

Comment: Can you share your model code.

Comment: Which model do you think of? I'm using the original User model without any changes.